# Google Tag manager fields to set in more settings?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have some things to understand in the Google tag manager, I am a little new and need some inputs. I quite don't understand what the Field to set option in more settings is all about. What does it do and what are these over ride settings in it?

Could anyone help me understand this part of Google TM and how it can be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

This document lists all of the configurable field names for analytics.js: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

By specifying the name of the input field you can override the value for that specific information. For example, if I wanted to anonymize the IP (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#anonymizeIp) of the sent hit I would write as name of field `anonymizeIp` and value equals `true`.

If you want to override the title (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#title) of a page you can set `title` as field name and a Custom JavaScript variable as value that generate dynamically the string of the title.

The same criterion applies to the other fields.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Fields to Set in the GA4 Configuration tag to set parameters (e.g., tracking ID, user ID, or cookie domain) that need to remain consistent across all events on a page. GA4 Event tags inherit the parameters of the GA4 Configuration tag. Parameters set by the GA4 Configuration tag remain static for all events occurring on a page. The parameters are refreshed only when the Configuration tag fires again, typically the next time the page is loaded.

If an Event tag has a parameter with the same name as a Configuration tag parameter, the Event tag parameter value will override that of the Configuration tag, but only for that event. All other Event tags that do not have the same parameter name will continue to reference the parameter value initially set by the Configuration tag.